# mutt: reply email from console

Tags: bash, email, mutt, reply

I'm using mutt to send me an e-mail when certain event happens:

```
if [ ... ]
then
  echo "Content" | mutt -s "Subject" -- "my.email@mail.com"
fi
```

This will send me a new email every time, but I would like that it replies the same e-mail over and over so there is only one e-mail "thread" instead of a new thread for every e-mail.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the `In-Reply-To:` header, and the value will be the message-id of the original email.

I think you'll do this (untested)

```
echo "content" | 
mutt -s "Subject" -e 'my_hdr In-Reply-To: <abc123@example.com>' -- recipient@example.com
```